# Why is a loop of async HttpClient calls in Xamarin blocking untill all are finished?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've written a loop in Xamarin for Android where I load 5 images asynchronously using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. Initiating the 5 requests executes instantly, but I'm not getting *any* continuation before all 5 responses are completed - about 4 seconds later. Why are not the responses coming individually, asynchronously?

I don't know much about how threads are handled in Xamarin so I might be doing something wrong. Should I not call it from the UI thread? Is there any way I can specify a Scheduler or threading policy for HttpClient?

The code for the load function:

```
// This method is called 5 times in a foreach loop, initated from the UI thread, not awaited
private async void LoadAsync(String uri)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = await imgSvc.loadAndDecodeBitmap(uri);
    image.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public async Task<Bitmap> loadAndDecodeBitmap(String uri) { 
    var client = new HttpClient();
    byte[] data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
    return img;
}
```

**Edit**: Minimal, reproducable example in [this repo](https://github.com/Nilzor/xamarin-thread-block)

Try switching `ImagesToLoad` in that example between 5 and 1 and see how the load time for the *first* image changes dramatically (about 2 sec difference on my computer).

[Load log 10 images](https://pastebin.com/LeMCB0s8)
[Load log if I only load 1](https://pastebin.com/s1hLPKyn)

Comment: Can you show the loop of async calls as a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue. The solution you linked to is just an bare bones project.

Comment: Please edit your question so it does contain the code where you call these methods?

Comment: Sorry I linked to the wrong branch. Check out branch "laptop" https://github.com/Nilzor/newsapp/tree/laptop/xamarin-news/xam-android-news/xam-android-news. I will provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example tomorrow

Comment: @Nilzor I might be blind but your repository does not show the LoadAsync() and loadAndDecodeBitmap() method. Do still have to edit your question so it does contain the code which calls your LoadAsync/loadAndDecodeBitmap() methods.

Comment: @progman I've now provided link to a new, simpler solution at https://github.com/Nilzor/xamarin-thread-block . Just one class now: MainActivity

Comment: @Nilzor There is something wrong with your async/await chain. Your initial call to LoadImages(); don't use the await keyword, so it is a synchronous method call. This doesn't look right. You might want to use Task.Factory.StartNew() to actually create a task which runs asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClient` scales badly in when run in parallell. It seems to be using only a few (1?) threads behind the scene, which are interdependent and can block each other, no matter if we wrap it in `Task.Run`. I came to this conclusion after swapping `Client.GetByteArrayAsync()` with `Task.Delay(1000)`. They behave vastly different.

Running 1 or 10 `Task.Delay(1000)` in parallell both give me the first result in just above ~1200ms. See commit `ff2a8e9` in [the repo](https://github.com/Nilzor/xamarin-thread-block) - swap `LoadAndDecodeBitmapFake` with `LoadAndDecodeBitmapFake`.

Running 1 `Client.GetByteArrayAsync()` give me the first result after ~1300ms while running 10 of them gives me the first result after ~5000ms. Se commit `561691f`

Turns out the optimal solution is to run them in serial - awaiting every single execution instead of lumping them and running `await Task.WhenAll()` on all 10. See commit `eaa0f18`. Then I get the first result after ~1400ms and the last after ~2000ms!

Sounds like a design flaw with `HttpClient` or something broken in the rewrite/wrapping to monodroid.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider loading them all at the same time using `Task.WhenAll`. You are also creating multiple instance of `HttpClient` which can have negative effects on performance.

First updating call to avoid using `async void`.

*ArticleTeaserView.cs*

```
public async Task SetModel(ArticleTeaser model) {
    title.SetText(model.promotionContent.title.value, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    description.SetText(model.promotionContent.description.value, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    try {
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(model.promotionContent.imageAsset.urls[0].url);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Image " + (++ctr) + " load starting...");
        await LoadAsync(model.promotionContent.imageAsset.GetUrlWithMinHeight(240), image);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Image " + ctr + " load completed");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.Debug(TAG, ex.Message);
    }
}

static ImageSvc imgSvc = new ImageSvc(); //should consider injecting service

private async Task<Image> LoadAsync(String uri, ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = await imgSvc.loadAndDecodeBitmap(uri);
    image.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

//Use only one shared instance of `HttpClient` for the life of the application
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<Bitmap> loadAndDecodeBitmap(String uri) {        
    byte[] data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
    return img;
}
```

Finally assuming you have a collection of urls. You create all the tasks and invoke all of them at the same time.

*MainActivity.cs*

```
private event EventHandler LoadData = delegate { };

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    InitViews();
    LoadData += onDataLoading; // subscribe to event
    LoadData(this, EventArgs.Empty); // raise event
}

//async void allowed on event handlers (actual event handler)
//*OnCreate* is not an event handler. Just a based method.
private async void onDataLoading(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    LoadData -= onDataLoading;
    await LoadDataAsync();
}

private void InitViews() {
    //...
}

private async Task LoadDataAsync() {
    var svc = new NewsService();
    var promContent = svc.syncLoadStrong();
    await BindView(promContent);
}

private async Task BindView(ArticleList list) {
    Log.Debug(TAG, "Binding MainActivity");
    ViewGroup scroller = FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Resource.Id.scroller);        
    if (list != null) {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (ArticleTeaser teaser in list) {
            var atv = new ArticleTeaserView(this, null);
            tasks.Add(atv.SetModel(teaser));
            scroller.AddView(atv);
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you are not mixing blocking calls like `.Result`, `.Wait()` with async/await calls and also avoid using `async void` unless it is for an event handler.

Comment: Thanks, good tips here, unfortunately none of them fixed the issue. I implemented them in this branch: https://github.com/Nilzor/newsapp/tree/laptop/xamarin-news/xam-android-news/xam-android-news . Struggling with ridding "async void" completely because the root method is Android's onCreate - cannot change signature of that

Comment: @Nilzor then create you own event and event handler and raise it in the onCreate

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use a single instance of an HttpClient object. As stated [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69954), you can reuse it to handle multipe instances.

The problem you are facing is because each time an HttpClient object is created, a connection is opened and this operation takes some time. Likewise, disposing each of the instances requires the connection to be closed and this may have an impact over other requests.